# Dividing zeros out of the denominator

Tags: rational-functions

Take the equation $\displaystyle y=\frac{x^2+x-6}{x^2-4}$, which is formed from simplifying $\displaystyle y= \frac{(x+3)(x-2)}{(x+2)(x-2)}$.

If we divide out $(x-2)$, from the numerator, we get the function $\displaystyle y = \frac{x+3}{x+2}$ which is defined for all real numbers except where $x =  -2$, where there is an infinite discontinuity.

However, if we look at the original function, wouldn't 2 be a removable discontinuity? Multiplying the equation by $\displaystyle \frac{x-2}{x-2}$ doesn't change the equation, except where $x=2$, because the denominator is now 0. I understand that the limit exists, yet [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%5E2%2Bx-6%29%2F%28x%5E2-4%29+at+x+%3D+2) seems to say that not only the limit, but the point actually exists. We couldn't have divided $(x-2)$ out if the denominator was equal to 0. Have I gone horribly wrong somewhere?

Comment: Alpha automatically removes removable singularities (at least when it spots it ;-))

Comment: It's actually common practice in some of the advanced parts of mathematics to have functions with removable discontinuities be defined at those "undefined" points by taking limits.

Answer (score 1):

The point does not exist, as the division by zero is not defined. Wolfram Alpha just gives you the limit as you can see in this [example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%281/x%29%2ax%20at%20x%20=%200) too. However the limit exists so you can divide $(x-2)$ from the numerator like you said but in this case you have always that $x \neq 2$ because you consider the limit so canceling the term is a valid step to get the function without the disconuity.

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram Alpha is just sloppy. If you put in x/x at x=0 you get x/x= 1 at x=0. It may be that the practice of ignoring this is encouraged by practical applications because , when we get an expression, The cancelling parts were introduced spuriously to begin with. What actual circumstances would realistically have such canceling parts?